# Using indexing and iteration to reformat values with Numpy Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, indexing

I want to make a code that goes through the lists within `vals` array one by one for each unique `digit_vals` value. The `digit_vals` value shows the nth number for the expected output, so since the first value in `digit_vals` is 24 then it means that all the numbers before it will be a filled with zeroes and the 24th number will contain value from `vals`. Since there are two 24s within `digit_vals` it means that the 2nd index within the first list of `vals` (`[-3.3, -4.3, 23.05, 23.08, 23.88, 3.72]`) will contain the 24th value in the Expected Output which is `-4.3`. The 4th index of the 2nd list within  `vals` will contain the value for the 27th value in `digit_vals` and so on. The gaps between the `digit_vals` will be filled with zeroes as well in the results so between 24 and 27 there will be 2 zeroes for the 25th and 26th place respectively. How would I be able to code this function that allows me to achieve the Expected Output below?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

digit_vals = np.array([24, 24, 27, 27, 27, 27,
                       28, 28, 28, 31])

vals = np.array([list([-3.3, -4.3, 23.05, 23.08, 23.88, 3.72]),
 list([2.3, 2.05, 3.08, -4.88, 4.72]),
 list([5.3, 2.05, 6.08, -13.88, -17.2]),
 list([9.05, 6.08, 3.88, -13.72])], dtype=object)
```

Expected Output:

```
array([  0.         ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         -4.3,      ,   0.        ,   0.        ,  -4.88      ,
          6.08,     ,   0         ,   9.05])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if I understand your question correctly, then your output array should be one element longer, with one more zero between to `6.08` value and the `9.05` value, because the `9.05` should be at index position 31 (the other values match their index position specified in `digit_vals`).
The hardest part of this question is transforming the information in the `digits_vals` array into two arrays that correctly index into each `vals` array list, and into the correct index position in the output array.
Because you're already using numpy, I think this is a reasonable approach

```
val_ind = []
out_ind = []
for ind, cnt in enumerate(np.bincount(digit_vals)):
    if cnt > 0:
        val_ind.append(cnt-1)
        out_ind.append(ind)
```

Calculate the number of occurrences of each value in `digits_vals` and use that count (minus one for zero indexing) as the index into each list within the `vals` array. Each unique number in `digits_vals` is identified by capturing the index for each value with a nonzero count, assuming `digits_vals` will be ordered, as specified in the question example.

Once you have the index lists built, it is straightforward to build the output array:

```
out_arr = np.zeros(np.max(digit_vals)+1)
for r_ind, (v_ind, o_ind) in enumerate(zip(val_ind, out_ind)):
    out_arr[o_ind] = vals[r_ind][v_ind]
```

Again, the enumeration provides the row index for extracting the correct row's data from the `vals` array. I've confirmed this reproduces the output array you provided, including the fix noted above. Hopefully I understood your question correctly, and made reasonable assumptions. If so, please update your question with a little more detail describing assumptions, etc.

Comment: Thank youi that works

Comment: Hi could you take a look at this issue as well it is relating to this issue. It just fetches the  max and min values as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660762/getting-the-max-min-and-last-index-of-formatted-arrays-numpy-python.