# Getting the max, min and last index of formatted arrays Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I want to make a code that goes through the lists within `vals` array one by one for each unique `digit_vals` value. The `digit_vals` value shows the nth number for the expected output, so since the first value in `digit_vals` is 24 then it means that all the numbers before it will be a filled with zeroes and the 24th number will contain value from `vals`. Since there are two 24s within `digit_vals` it means that the 2nd index within the first list of `vals` is the last index so it will take ([-3.3, -4.3]) to get the max:-3.3,min:-4.3 and last index: `-4.3` value out of (`[-3.3, -4.3, 23.05, 23.08, 23.88, 3.72]`) will contain the 24th value in the Expected Output. The 4th index of the 2nd list within `vals` will contain the value for the 27th value in `digit_vals` and so on. The gaps between the `digit_vals` will be filled with zeroes as well in the results so between 24 and 27 there will be 2 zeroes for the 25th and 26th place respectively. I want modify `out_arr` to create a 2d array with identical values like `[[zeroes],[zeroes],[zeroes]]`. The `max` and `min` values also don't work `max/min(vals[r_ind][v_ind])`.How would I be able to fix those 2 functions?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

digit_vals = np.array([24, 24, 27, 27, 27, 27,
                       28, 28, 28, 31])

vals = np.array([list([-3.3, -4.3, 23.05, 23.08, 23.88, 3.72]),
 list([2.3, 2.05, 3.08, -4.88, 4.72]),
 list([5.3, 2.05, 6.08, -13.88, -17.2]),
 list([9.05, 6.08, 3.88, -13.72])], dtype=object)

def Monthly_CAP_movement():
    #Val_ind is used to count the number of repetitive numbers
    #out_ind shows the unique numbers 

    val_ind = []
    out_ind = []
    for ind, cnt in enumerate(np.bincount(digit_vals)):
        if cnt > 0:
            val_ind.append(cnt-1)
            out_ind.append(ind)

    # Turn the out_arr function to a 2 dimensional of coppied arrays [[zeroes],[zeroes],[zeroes]]
    # Assign 3 of the zeroes one for each (last index, Max and Min)
    out_arr = np.zeros(np.max(digit_vals)+1)
    for r_ind, (v_ind, o_ind) in enumerate(zip(val_ind, out_ind)):
        # Last Index Recording
        out_arr[0][o_ind] = vals[r_ind][v_ind]
        # Max Recording 
        out_arr[1][o_ind] = max(vals[r_ind][v_ind])
        # Min Recording
        out_arr[2][o_ind] = min(vals[r_ind][v_ind])
```

Expected Output:

```
Last Index: [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
 -4.3   0.    0.   -4.88  6.08  0.    0.    9.05]
Max Value: [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
 -3.3   0.    0.   3.08   6.08  0.    0.    9.05]
Min Value: [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
 -4.3   0.    0.   -4.88  2.05  0.    0.    9.05]
```

Comment: Ok, I can help. Please provide a link to the previous question, and say you want to expand on it to include a function applied across an array slice. I assume a moderator will come along at some point to clarify if that is not the right approach

Comment: Thanks here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658435/using-indexing-and-iteration-to-reformat-values-with-numpy-pandas-python

Comment: @frederick-douglas-pearce Hi I have another question that is related to this issue please take a look if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70678411/getting-the-last-index-max-min-of-lists-by-using-numpy-pandas Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review list/array slicing in numpy (e.g. [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) or [array slicing](https://towardsdatascience.com/slicing-numpy-arrays-like-a-ninja-e4910670ceb0)). First off, `out_arr` should be initialized with three rows. Then, the min and max need to be computed across a slice containing all values up to the `v_ind` value:

```
val_ind = []
out_ind = []
for ind, cnt in enumerate(np.bincount(digit_vals)):
    if cnt > 0:
        val_ind.append(cnt-1)
        out_ind.append(ind)
out_arr = np.zeros((3, np.max(digit_vals)+1))
for r_ind, (v_ind, o_ind) in enumerate(zip(val_ind, out_ind)):
    out_arr[0, o_ind] = vals[r_ind][v_ind]
    out_arr[1, o_ind] = np.max(vals[r_ind][:v_ind+1])
    out_arr[2, o_ind] = np.min(vals[r_ind][:v_ind+1])
```

[image: Resulting Output]

A slice doesn't return the last value so that is why you need the `v_ind+1`, as noted in the links above.